# Is $\frac{1}{x}$ integrable?

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I am taking a course on theory of integrals and measure, where I have learned a very fundamental definition of integral. One of the things I've learned is that $f$ is integrable iff $\int|f|<\infty$. Then, according to this definition, $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ wouldn't be integrable, since the integral of $|f(x)|=|\frac{1}{x}|$ diverges. However, I can calculate $\int_a^b\frac{1}{x}dx$ for any $a, b \in (-\infty, +\infty)$ and this isn't problematic at all. How do I deal with this?

Comment: But $\left|\frac{1}{x}\right|<\infty$ if e.g. $x\in[a,b]$ with eirher $a>0$ or $b<0$, so the function is not prevented from being integrable *on $[a,b]$*. It is not integrable if $a\le0\le b$. (I am not sure about your "iff" though: the condition $|f|<\infty$ is necessary but not sufficient for the function to be integrable.)

Comment: If $a<0<b$, it is **extremely** problematic.

Comment: @Gae.S.Wasn't careful enough - updated.

Comment: @Gae.S. I don't unserstand why. The anti-derivative is $ln(|x|)$ and that isn't problematic

Comment: @StinkingBishop I wasn't talking to you specifically, but rather to kubo.

Comment: @kubo: why don't you stick to the definition in your book/lectures? after all "integrable" is just a name and it may have different meaning in different contexts. I think you are referring to Lp-spaces definition of Lp-integrable. Then it should be clear: https://planetmath.org/summablefunction

Comment: @kubo I beg to differ: the set of antiderivatives of $\frac1x$ on $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ is a two-dimensional affine space, specifically $f'(x)=\frac1x$ for all $x\ne0$ if and only if there are $c_1, c_2\in\Bbb R$ such that $f(x)=\begin{cases}c_1+\ln x&\text{if }x>0\\ c_2+\ln(-x)&\text{if }x<0\end{cases}$. Anyways, the theorem "if $F$ is an antiderivative of $g$ on $X$, then the Lebesgue/improper Riemann integral $\int_a^b g\,dx$ is equal to $F(b)-F(a)$" holds under specific hypothesis, one of which being that $X$ should be an interval.

Answer (score 2):

I think your real difficulty is that we don't say "$f$ is integrable," but rather "$f$ is integrable over $D$" where $D$ is some domain.

Your definition works fine if the domain is an interval that doesn't contain $0$.

Answer (score 0):

I think the OP is referring to the fact that, if a function $f$ is the derivative of another function $g$, then
$$
  \int_a^bf(x)\, dx = g(b)-g(a).
  \tag{1}
  $$
Since $1/x$ is the derivative of $\ln(|x|)$,  we would then have  that
$$
  \int_a^b{1\over x}\, dx = \ln(|b|) - \ln(|a|).
  \tag{2}
  $$

The error in this argument is that for (1) to hold, one needs that $g'(x)=f(x)$ for EVERY $x$ in $[a,b]$.  Since
$$
  {d\over dx}\ln(|x|) = {1\over x}
  $$
is only true if $x\neq 0$, one may not allow 0 to be in the interval  $[a,b]$ for (2) to hold!

Comment: I think I was downvoted by someone who didn't care to read the post to the end!  In any case an explanation of the reason for the downvote would be much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

You can deal with it using [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) taking symmetric boundaries in limit. When $a<0<b$
$$\int\limits_{a}^{b}\frac{dx}{x}=\lim\limits_{\varepsilon \to 0+}\left(\int\limits_{a}^{-\varepsilon}+\int\limits_{\varepsilon}^{b}\right)\frac{dx}{x}$$

Comment: Constructive critique is welcome, especially for correct answer.

Comment: Well, it seems apparent to me: the person is confused about the difference between computing a Lebesgue/Riemann integral and computing the difference of an antiderivative. You are saying: "The very thing which is confusing you is Cauchy-correct".

Comment: @Gae. S. In OP main question is "How do I deal with this?" and my variant gives one possible, **correct**, answer. Your proposal is what you conjectured.

Comment: I agree that we disagree. I won't downvote and I won't answer the question anyways.

Comment: @Gae. S. It is not about agreement or disagreement, but about critique with no arguments or with wrong arguments - answer brought by me is classical one in a lot of books, in wiki etc.

Comment: I gave you my argument, and your position is that my understanding of the question is partial. Nevertheless, it is still my belief that your answer clings to a specific part of the question, which the asker posed without realising that it doesn't capture the nature of his misunderstanding. I am also quite adamant in thinking that the net effect will be to confuse the asker more than he already is about Riemann and Lebesgue integration.That is the nature of our disagreemen. However, I don't see a point in nagging you any further, all the more because I don't care to write an answer of mine.

Comment: All the time you try to draw conclusions for me, in place of me and attribute your thoughts to me, also try to explain what the op meant. All this is deeply wrong and incorrect. I also do not see much point in continuing the conversation until you stop speculating other people's thoughts and opinions.